# Issue with URL data returned by get_file_contents used on XML feed

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I am using `file_get_contents()` to retrieve xml feed data, for parsing. With the image URL's however, I am getting my base url prefixing the image URL - like this:-

**http://server.com/http://server2.com/image.png**

Here's my code:

```
<? php
$context = stream_context_create(
array(
    'http' => array(
        'follow_location' => false
    )
)
);
$content =file_get_contents("http://xyogasangeetax.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/latestclips.xml", false, $context);
$data = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
foreach($data->channel->item as $entry)
{
if ($media = $entry->children('media', TRUE)) {
$attributes = $media->content->attributes();
$src = $play_attributes['url'];
if ($media->thumbnail) {
$attributes = $media->thumbnail->attributes();
$imgsrc = (string)$attributes['url'];
echo "<img src=\"'$imgsrc'\" alt=\"\" \/>";
}
}
$pub_date= explode("-",$entry->pubDate);
echo date('F d,Y',strtotime(trim($pub_date[0])));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete unneeded quotes:

change

```
echo "<img src=\"'$imgsrc'\" alt=\"\" \/>";
```

to

```
echo "<img src=\"$imgsrc\" alt=\"\" \/>";
```